# How to compare two IntStreams without collecting or check if all elemnts of one Stream are present in an other stream?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Let x be a given stream with certain numbers:

```
IntStream x = IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5);
```

and y a stream to be tested

```
IntStream y = IntStream.of(5,5,4,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,1,5,3); //result should be true
IntStream y = IntStream.of(5,5,4,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,7,8,9); //result should be false
```

How do I check that y only consists of the numbers x?

```
y.distinct().allMatch(i->???)
```

??? I'm stuck here with what I'm supposed to insert at this point to do the check.

Comment: You have to collect `x` to a `Set`. If they're not ordered, there isn't much else you can do.

Comment: @AndyTurner y.distinct().allMatch(i->x.collect(Collectors.toSet()).contains(i)); gives me method collect in interface IntStream cannot be applied to given types; error. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `x.boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet())`. `IntStream` doesn't contain boxed elements.

Comment: that also wouldn't work because you can only iterate a stream once. You have to collect `x` first, and store in a variable outside the `y.distinct()...` expression.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for pointing that out. I just noticed that when I tried it. Error message: stream has already been operated upon or closed. I use the approach of Prashant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I differ to the existing answer based on the question stated. If you were to check if all the elements of `streamY` are that from an existing `streamX`, you can perform an `allMatch` and <strike>not `findAny`</strike> as:

```
private boolean intStreamContainsAnother(IntStream streamOfX, IntStream streamOfY) {
    Set<Integer> setOfX = streamOfX.boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return streamOfY.allMatch(setOfX::contains);
}
```

Though from the requirements in the question, way to perform that **without collecting** would not be possible for the reason that the *stream could be operated only once*.

```
private boolean intStreamContainsAnother(IntStream streamOfX, IntStream streamOfY) {
    return streamOfY.allMatch(ys -> streamOfX.anyMatch(xs -> xs == ys));
}
```

Comment: The first approach is clear and understandable and works. The second approach gives the error message : stream has already been operated upon or closed. I think for the same reason as @AndyTurner pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: @Trillian True. The `streamOfX` there would be consumed at the very first attempt to ensure the presence of `y` from a `streamOfY.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
Set<Integer> interestSet = x.boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

Optional<Integer> o = y.filter(a -> interestSet.contains(a)).findAny();

return o.isPresent();
```

Comment: gives me : method collect in interface IntStream cannot be applied to given types; error.

Comment: Could you please try now? Corrected it.

Comment: The answer here checks if one of the elements from `streamY` is present in the `interestSet` created out of `streamX`, it would return true. @Trillian Your question contradicts this answer.

Comment: @Naman You're right. You're right. I was happy to have found an approach at all and adapted it a bit so that it worked for me. I had to rewrite it like this

`OptionalInt o = y.filter(a -> !interestSet.contains(a)).findAny();`
`return !o.isPresent();`